# BBCODE hole, insertion of malicious styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bbcode

I have a system to parse BBCODE to HTML tags.
But I have a problem. When I insert color the users can put also other styles. For Example:

```
[color=green;font-size:100px]green text[/color]
```

In this way the users can insert to the chat big words, it isn't good.
My parsing system --> [source](http://pastebin.com/08agPtfw)

What's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick fix you can replace the line

```
'/\[color=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/color\]/is',
```

with

```
'/\[color=([^;]*?)\](.*?)\[\/color\]/is',
```

This way it won't match on color-tags including a `;`, but still whatever the user enters behind `=` will be in the `<span>`-tag.

Another option (which may require more work) is to allow only certain colors:

```
'/\[color=(#\d{6}|green|blue|red|black)\](.*?)\[\/color\]/is',
```

This will allow hex colors (like `#000000`) and green, blue, red and black... you're free to add other colors.